# Bitbucket Continuous Integration with Bamboo OnDemand

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, bamboo, ondemand

I'm having trouble getting Bitbucket (Git repo) to trigger a Bamboo OnDemand (version 4.1.2-ondemand-rc9) build.  I followed the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Setting+Up+the+Bitbucket+Bamboo+Service) for setting up a Bamboo service from Bitbucket but it doesn't trigger the Plan to build.  Bamboo seems to work OK though; I can trigger builds manually without any problems. As a backup I changed the build strategy to "polling the repository for changes" and that worked.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Does Bitbucket support making CI notifications to Bamboo OnDemand?  If it helps I enabled the "Accept legacy remote API calls?" option in Bamboo's settings
2. Is there a way to get logs or errors from Bitbucket to debug?  That way I can see if it's making the call, and what the response is.

Thanks.
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to Atlassian support and they updated their documentation, turns out I goofed up the URL.  Following the instructions here helped out and it worked like a charm.

<s>https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Setting+Up+the+Bitbucket+Bamboo+Service</s>
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bamboo-service-management-278069514.html

Answer (score 1):

This is in case you still need to get at the logs: after your task has run in the Bamboo plan, click on the 'Logs' link and, in the logs summary window. you have the options to either download or view the detailed log. Good idea, if you chose 'View' to do so with right click so it allows you to open log in new tab.

BTW please note that the hyperlink mentioned above is no longer correct.